# Jupyter notebooks: Tornado pointing to incorrect path

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda, jupyter-notebook, tornado

I'm trying to run a Jupyter notebook. I installed Anaconda 5.3 with the Python 3.7 version. The notebook starts up, but the Kernel fails to run because it's pointing to another version of Tornado that I've installed for some of my ROS projects (output below). How do I ensure the Jupyter kernel is using Tornado installed in the Anaconda path?

```
[I 10:56:54.649 NotebookApp] KernelRestarter: restarting kernel (4/5), new random ports
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/dir/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "/dir/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/dir/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py", line 16, in <module>
    app.launch_new_instance()
  File "/dir/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/traitlets/config/application.py", line 657, in launch_instance
    app.initialize(argv)
  File "<decorator-gen-123>", line 2, in initialize
  File "/dir/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/traitlets/config/application.py", line 87, in catch_config_error
    return method(app, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/dir/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ipykernel/kernelapp.py", line 467, in initialize
    self.init_sockets()
  File "/dir/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ipykernel/kernelapp.py", line 260, in init_sockets
    self.init_iopub(context)
  File "/dir/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ipykernel/kernelapp.py", line 268, in init_iopub
    self.iopub_thread = IOPubThread(self.iopub_socket, pipe=True)
  File "/dir/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ipykernel/iostream.py", line 66, in __init__
    self.io_loop = IOLoop(make_current=False)
  File "/dir/ros_projects/forked/rosbridge_suite/rosbridge_server/src/tornado/util.py", line 208, in __new__
    instance.initialize(**args)
  File "/dir/ros_projects/forked/rosbridge_suite/rosbridge_server/src/tornado/platform/epoll.py", line 26, in initialize
    super(EPollIOLoop, self).initialize(impl=select.epoll(), **kwargs)
TypeError: initialize() got an unexpected keyword argument 'make_current'
[W 10:56:57.665 NotebookApp] KernelRestarter: restart failed
[W 10:56:57.666 NotebookApp] Kernel 2dd183ff-850d-4f79-945c-c8f56f1e695e died, removing from map.
```

Comment: Have you considered using Virtual Env in `Anaconda` ??

Comment: Yes, this is after creating an environment in Anaconda and sourcing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A little late, but answering my own question. PYTHONPATH was set for a bunch of other projects. Since conda doesn't set PYTHONPATH, running

```
unset PYTHONPATH
```

did the trick.